# Update Preview inconsistent behaviour

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t

I have a DD4T based website in Tridion 2011 SP1 using XPM.

When I update any content and click update preview it sometimes updates the preview with the new content and sometimes doesn't. Also it is showing the old contents in other edited regions after clicking U.P. which I had added yesterday. Please suggest. 
Earlier the preview was not at all working but after moving the ambient from `<httpmodule>` to `<modules>` in web.config fixed but seems it's not behaving perfectly.

I have checked the CP table in session preview db, the contents are getting added and cleared after exiting.

Answer (score 6):

Session Preview cannot deal well with application caching, as that basically stops the page/application from requesting new content from the Broker (which session Preview would intersect and get from the Session preview DB).

By default DD4T has caching enabled, which basically stops it from working correctly right there. Now there is a certain level of caching which you can allow, but I keep forgetting the exact details. So check out this [blog post from Albert Romkes](http://albertromkes.com/2013/01/24/troubleshooting-the-sdl-tridion-experience-manager-with-session-preview/), as he states in there, when trying to set it all up and figuring it all out, turn off caching...

Comment: I have tried adding <add key="CacheSettings_CallBackInterval" value="30"/> in web.config but there is no change.

Comment: @user734 That is not turning it off ;)

Comment: No, everytime it shows the old contents on 'Update preview' after refreshing though I didn't change those components today. And the components which I edit sometime works and not on UP. By setting the above in config I thought it would bring from broker after 30 secs but it's not working and I am not sure from where the old contents changed 3 days back are coming.

Comment: @user734 my guess is that that is coming from DD4T application caching, but I can't say for sure of course

Comment: How can I atleast clear that cache for a fresh check.

Comment: Refresh app pool, or restart IIS

Comment: I did that for both my website and odata website. Also there were cache enabled for this specific DD4T website in odata storage by pub id which I have set as false now but no luck.

Comment: @user734 then I have a feeling there is something wrong with your entire configuration, you better edit the question and add additional information in there (like you config files etc), because I have no clue what else could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks Bart! Actually the second part of my original question (it is showing the old contents in other edited regions after clicking U.P. which I had added yesterday.) was because the components were somehow updated and hence were showing the contents updated few days back. For the first part that it's updating contents and not sometimes, I have observed a common pattern. After editing the content if  I click UP after say 10 secs then it updates but not if I click UP instantly. Any clue? I already have the caching disabled in storage.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/update-preview-weird-behaviour-in-dd4t